# I am getting an error "Type conflicts with the imported type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a class file in C# called Users. I want to create an instance of a class from within the same class file. I thought had been able to do this in the past. When I try here. I get the message "The type Users in "" conflicts with the imported type "Users" in.

Is it possible to create an instance of a class within the class file itself.  If so, can someone tell me what I am missing?

```
 public class Users
    {
   
public int ID { get; set; }
public int Cityid { get; set; }
public bool Active { get; set; }
     
        
public Users GetUserforedit(int id)
```

Comment: May be you want: `public static Users GetUserforedit(int id)` - note `static`. Call it like this: `Users users = Users.GetUserforedit(1);`.

Comment: The fact that you are _still_ getting an error, even if you can overcome it, makes it sound like you still have a conflict within the namespace. Do your classes _have_ a namespace? Try wrapping your `Users` class within a namespace declaration.

Comment: Also, it would be interesting to see what happens if you change your class name to something else, like "AppUsers". If the conflict goes away, it'd definitely be the case that there was another "Users" class defined there somewhere (and, it might not be _your_ class: it could be a framework class!)

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason why you couldn't have an instance method of a class that returned an instance of the class itself, although it's more common to make such a method a `static` method rather than an instance method.

(In fact, if you couldn't do that, you wouldn't be able to have methods like `Clone()`!)

As for your error messages, two possibilities occur:

The most obvious cause would be that there's another class called `Users` in either the same namespace, or a namespace you're importing. Do you have a web page called `Users`? Another, earlier version of your class file, perhaps?

The other possibility would be that your class not being within a namespace is somehow confusing the compiler. Try wrapping the class in a namespace, and see if you now get at least a more useful error message.

Comment: Here is the weird thing: If I add #pragma warning disable CS0436 above it everything compiles and it works.  I guess I am wondering now where this other reference could be?

Comment: If you really want to dig deeply into this, you could try an open-source file compare tool such as https://winmerge.org/, and compare the files from the two versions to each other, and see what changed!

Answer (score 0):

I created an example that is similar to your example and does what you want.

```
    public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Cityid { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }
       
        private User GetUserForEdit(int id)
        {
            return new User()
            {
                Id = id,
                Active = true,
                Cityid = 1
            };
        }
        public void TestUser()
        {
            User user = GetUserForEdit(1); //creating an instance of a class within the class file itself.
            Console.WriteLine(user.Id + " " + user.Active + " " + user.Cityid);
        }
    }
```

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            User user = new User();
            user.TestUser();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Nope. Same result. I feel like this is something simple. I am going to create a new project and add each thing in and see what happens.

Comment: OK, so I created a new solution from scratch. I then added the pages I needed back along with the classes. Intellisense said I had an error on the user class file but allowed me to reference the class file in the app code folder. Everything is working now.  My next question is where are those changes made.  I would love to be able to fix those if I do something like that again.